# Can an API user be set inactive automatically? API returned "cannot reparent record" for active user

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, user, session, user-admin

I have a web application that uses the Salesforce API to create Contact, Account, Opportunity records. We set up an administrator user with full permissions to use as the Oauth login user, and I use it as an admin for development. I went on vacation so this system admin user was being used for API access only for over a week.

Then all of a sudden the system started returning errors to me (Django Python) `SalesforceError: {u'errorCode': u'CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD', u'fields': [], u'message': u'owner is inactive, cannot reparent record'}` . Thing is the owner in this case should be the system user I created and any other records that would have been touched with it are owned by active users. I logged into the SF web interface with my admin user, the errors stopped.

My question is - is it possible that the user was flagged as inactive automatically? I can't find a setting that would change this. Would it be caused by something else or am I on the right track?

Comment: If your system user would have been set as inactive, the login attempt itself would have failed. Instead, the error says that the owner is inactive, which means that the owner of the record is inactive and not the user who is trying to update. If you can identify the records that returned this error, you can check which user is set as owner for those records.

Comment: The application doesn't log in very frequently, only on reboot or if the token expired. This error popped up when the system tried to create a new record, where there is no owner explicitly set and the api user owns the record